# How to set Datasource pointing to multiple Database at the time crystal report creation

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need to create a Crystal Report and have to set Datasource location pointing to Development, Testing and Production servers. The created crystal report will be placed in database table and fetched at the time of report generation by passing the credentials(Development or production). But whatever Datasource given at the time of creation it is pointing to that only cant able to change the datasource through the code.

Please help me in this. I need a Crystal Report generated with multiple datasource connections.

In C# I have written code as shown below:

```
oReport.SetDatabaseLogon(gcUser, gcPassword, gcDB, gcDB);
oReport.DataSourceConnections[0].SetLogon(gcUser, gcPassword);
```

Comment: How do you decide which environment to use? Is it user selects in the UI between dev, test or production and based on that selection you need to load the report?

Comment: You may try to abstract the database using XSD files and .NET Datasets. So you would just fill the datasets from your databases.

Comment: The environment will be decided by the web config file, server details will be stored in database and are fetched in runtime and passed to the rpt file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create 1 report with multiple saved connections. You can apply the connection on the fly in your code, when running the report or you can save multiple reports, which will differ just by the connection. There are some tools , which can be used to replace report's database connection. This one http://r-tagsoftware.com/Pages/CrystalDataSource can process single report for free

Comment: How can we apply connection on fly in code, I have given Current Datasource for the View which I have used in rpt file and tried to modify it in code but it is not getting effected. Rpt file is point to the connection which we have given at the time of creation. Please help me what we need to do at the time of rpt file creation in-order to achieve the connection change through the code.